# ОбновлениеTextView из потока в Android

Tags: java, android

Подскажите, как реализуется обновление элементов интерфейса, если оно может постоянно меняться?

К примеру есть `TextView`. Как реализовать вызов `String text = GetNewText(); TextView tv.setText();` каждую секунду?

С одной стороны нужен поток, но из него нельзя менять интерфейс. Если будет поток, то как из него правильно выйти при смене layout?

Comment: Что значит выйти из потока при смене layout? Зачем? Поток сам завершится когда выполнит весь код который в нем, если там конечно не бесконечный цикл.

Answer (score 2):

Вместо потока следует использовать `AsynkTask` у которой метод `doInBackground()` выполняется в фоновом потоке а `onPreExecute`, `onPostExecute` и `onProgressUpdate` в главном потоке.

Но если уж совсем хочется чтоб код выполнился в главном потоке то можно использовать `Handler`, метод `post` у любого `View`, или что-то типа

```
MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        Log.d("UI thread", "I am the UI thread");
    }
});
```

Comment: Задача вызывать код каждую секунду. Через AsynkTask я вызову код один раз. Или предлагаете добавить бесконечный цикл?

Comment: Как вариант - бесконечный цикл в `doInBackground()` и вывод результата через `onProgressUpdate()`, а когда таска станет не нужна сделать ей `cancel()`

Comment: лучше использовать `onProgressUpdate()` вместо доступа через `runOnUiThread()` из `doInBackground()`

Comment: лучше не использовать AsyncTask :)

Comment: По итогам. Показалось хорошим решение на TimerTask, но на выходе после cancel(); и purge(); задача все равно умудрялась вызваться и все падало, так как layout уже другой. Хотя, может это я где ошибся. В итоге взял AsynkTask, он вполне работает, удается ничего не запароть. Других работающих решений не вижу.  sleep(100) не сильно отразится на батарейке?

Answer (score 0):

```
 timer = new CountDownTimer(10* 1000, 1000) { //каждую секунду в течении 10 секунд

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
               String text = GetNewText(); 
               TextView tv.setText(); 
            }

            public void onFinish() {
               super.onFinish(result);
            }
 }.start();
```