# обновить textview из Runnable

Tags: java, android, многопоточность

Есть такой цикл, хочу обновить textview из цикла, по логам поток идет, но textview обновляется лишь с последним значением, когда цикл достигае конца, в данном случае 0.

```
private void start() {
    Thread th = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        for (int i = 5; i>=0; i--) {
                            try {
                                Log.i(TAG, "поток: " + i);
                                textViewThread.setText(String.valueOf(i));
                                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
                            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
        }
    });
    th.start();
}
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [ОбновлениеTextView из потока в Android](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/419585/%d0%9e%d0%b1%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5textview-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%bf%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%b2-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private void startTimerThread() {
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            for (int i = 5; i>=0; i--) {
                try {
                    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
                }    
                catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                handler.post(new Runnable(){
                    public void run() {
                       textView.setText(String.valueOf(i);
                }
            });
            }
        }
    };
    new Thread(runnable).start();
}
```

Но, мне кажется, для этого лучше заюзать `AsyncTask`:

```
public class Timer extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {
    @Override
    public void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        for (int i = 5; i>=0; i--) {
            try {
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally {
                publishProgress(i);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onProgessUpdate(Integer... progress) {
        textView.setText(String.valueOf(progress[0]));
    }
}
```

Все писал без IDE, пррверьте

Comment: спасибо, верно.

Comment: Не за что, удачи!